# Method to find colossally abundant numbers?

Tags: number-theory, inequality, exponentiation, divisor-sum

Colossally abundant numbers are positive integers $n$ for which there exists a positive exponent $\epsilon$ such that

$$\frac{\sigma(n)}{n^{1+\epsilon}}>\frac{\sigma(m)}{m^{1+\epsilon}}$$

for all integers $m>1,m\ne n$. Here, $\sigma(n)$ denotes the sum-of-divisors function $\sum_{d|n}d$.

The first few colossally abundant numbers are $2,6,12,60,120,360...$ (from Wolfram Mathworld [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ColossallyAbundantNumber.html)).

My question is, how does one go about discovering such numbers, or proving that a number is colossally abundant? One can't test individually for all combinations of $n,m,\epsilon$, so there must be an algebraic method. What is it? (Google is no help.)

**UPDATE**

In light of @Mindlack's and @John Omielan's helpful comments below, and in order not to end up with an extended comment section, I thought it might be good to elaborate on my original question here.

1. @John: Yes, I take your point, but it still sounds a lot like
   searching for a needle in a haystack. Maybe that's what you're
   trying to say?
2. @Mindlack:

   - OK, so setting $n=2$ gives $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n^{1+\epsilon}}=\frac{\sigma(2)}{2^{1+\epsilon}}=\frac{3}{2^{1+\epsilon}}$, with you so far
   - But where does $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}=\sum_{d|n}\frac{n/d}{n}$ come from? It seems to me that we have $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}=\frac{\sum_{d|n}d}{n}$. So you are suggesting that $\frac{\sum_{d|n}d}{n}=\sum_{d|n}\frac{n/d}{n}$... How so? Surely we should have $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}=\frac{\sum_{d|n}d}{n}=\sum_{d|n}\frac{d}{n}$
   - And... well, there I lose you. I can't follow the rest because I can't really get past this one issue

I'm 100% sure it's me being stupid - I'm teaching myself all this stuff for the first time, and on my own. I realise that no one on MathStackExchange signs up to hold the hands of newbies, but if you have the time (or anyone else does) I'd really appreciate some clarification.

BTW: aren't we all, as a community and as a species, incredibly that such sites exist? Wow.

Comment: What is $\sigma$ here?

Comment: @JackCrawford $\sigma (n)$ denotes the sum of divisors of $n$.

Comment: I'll modify the question. Apologies.

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward The [Properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossally_abundant_number#Properties) sub-section of Wikipedia's Colossally abundant number page says it's based on Grönwall's theorem which says "there is an increasing sequence of integers $n$ such that for these integers $\sigma(n)$ is roughly the same size as $e^{\gamma}n\log(\log(n))$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant". It doesn't give exact details on how to use this, but I believe $n^{\epsilon}$ is compared to $e^{\gamma}n\log(\log(n))$ to determine it's epsilon & some nearby values are checked to confirm.

Comment: Hi @John. Yes, but I'm not sure how this helps me...

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward It was getting late so I was about to go to bed and I wasn't exactly sure of the details myself, so I just left a comment for you. Grönwall's theorem gives that there's an eventual constant limit of $\sigma(n) / n(\ln(\ln(n)))$ going to $e^{\gamma}$. There's a MathWorld visual [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GronwallsTheorem.html). Since $n^{\epsilon}$ grows faster than $\ln(\ln(n))$, it means for any fixed $\epsilon$, all $\sigma(n) / n^{1+\epsilon}$ will be smaller. If you find where $\sigma(n) / n$ is locally max., you can check if an $\epsilon$ works. I believe ...

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward (cont.) this is why the values of $\sigma(n)/n$ for the colossally abundant numbers shown in your Mathworld link form a strictly increasing list. I'm not sure of the exact & most efficient way to confirm any given value is a colossally abundant number, as it depends on how, for any $\epsilon$ being checked, how fast $\sigma(n)/n^{1+\epsilon}$ decreases compared to the general upper limit of $e^{\gamma}\ln(\ln(n))$. The graph I linked to above shows how the values can fluctuate, but they eventually are all less than the dashed blue line. I don't know more details than this.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I put in output showing how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given some $\delta > 0,$ the correct exponent (to build a Colossally Abundant Number by prime factorization) for some prime $p$ is
$$ \left\lfloor \frac{\log (p^{1 + \delta} - 1) - \log(p^\delta - 1)}{\log p} \right\rfloor  \; - \; 1.  $$
This is [Theorem 10 on page 455 of Alaoglu and Erdos (1944)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e71e/d3a6549484fb0b41232ef046542eccbc60a7.pdf). For a fixed $\delta,$ the exponents either stay the same or decrease for increasing $p,$ and eventually the exponent 0 is reached, so there is your complete number. For a fixed $p,$ the exponent either stays the same or increases with **decreasing** $\delta.$

I'm not seeing any lists that show $\delta$ and the result, so here, if I call $f(\delta)$ the corresponding colossally abundant number for $\delta,$ I calculate $$ f(1) = 1, \; f(1/2) = 2, \; f(1/4) = 6, \; f(1/6) = 12, \; f(1/10) = 60, \; f(1/12) = 120,$$
then
$$ f(1/14) = 360, \; f(1/17) = 2520, \; f(1/25) = 5040, \; f(1/31) = 55440, \; f(1/39) = 720720,$$
 and so on as $\delta$ decreases.

If you want the first (largest) $\delta$ for which a favorite prime $p$ gets assigned exponent $k,$ let
$$  \delta = \frac{\log(p^{k+1} - 1) - \log(p^{k+1} - p)}{\log p}                        $$

Comment: I've marked this as answered (sorry @Mindlack, but this answer is more comprehensive; I really appreciate your input, though). But I do have one follow-up question: how are you identifying the values of $\delta$ out of an infinite range of possibilities?

Comment: Just a quick question, I heard this is an "effective construction for the set of all CA numbers", so does this mean that this will give me every single CA number with no exception?

Comment: @Horus yes.  I put various outputs and some of the code as other answers on this same question.

Comment: A quick question. Could you explain briefly how you derive your last equation for $\delta$ from the top equation appearing in the AE paper? Surely something simple, but I don’t see it right now.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying it backwards: given some $\epsilon >0$, it is easy to find an $N$ such that $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n^{1+\epsilon}} < 3/2^{1+\epsilon}$ for all $n \geq N$ (because $\sigma(n) \leq n\ln{n}+n$).

Then you just optimize $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n^{1+\epsilon}}$ over $2 \leq n \leq N$.

Comment: Hi @Mindlack. Thanks for this. I have two questions. (1) Can you steer me through the logic that gets you to $3/2^{1+\epsilon}$? (2) Can you point me to a source for the statement $\sigma(n) \le n \ln n+n$?

Comment: $3/2^{1+\epsilon}=\frac{\sigma(n)}{n^{1+\epsilon}}$ for $n=2$. For your second part, write $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}=\sum_{d|n}{\frac{n/d}{n}} \leq \sum_{1 \leq d \leq n}{d^{-1}} \leq \ln{n}+1$.

Comment: OK, this is going to take me some time to process... My thinking is not as advanced as yours! Please bear with me.

Comment: Hi again @Mindlack. Can you elaborate? I have no doubt at all that your suggestion is right, but I'm afraid I can't follow the logic. Specifically: (1) are you suggesting by searching for $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n^{1+\epsilon}}<\frac{3}{2^{1+\epsilon}}$ that I search for all $N$ that are *not* colossally abundant? That's an infinite set! (2) I can't follow the logic in your statement that $\sum_{d|n}\frac{n/d}{n}\le\sum_{1\le d\le n}d^{-1}$ - why is this true? (3) I also can't follow the logic in your statement that $\sum_{1\le d\le n}d^{-1}\le\ln n+1$ - why is this true?

Comment: (1): I suggest that you find an integer $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $\frac{\ln{n}+1}{n^{\epsilon}} < 3/2^{1+\epsilon}$ for all $n \geq N$. Yes, it is going to be large, so you have to keep $\epsilon$ not too small.

Comment: (2): $\sum_{d|n}{\frac{n/d}{n}}=\sum_{d|n}{\frac{1}{d}} \leq \sum_{1 \leq d \leq n}{\frac{1}{d}}.$

Comment: (3): use that for all $d \geq 2$, $\frac{1}{d} \leq \int_{d-1}^d{\frac{dx}{x}}.$

Comment: Thanks @Mindlack. I've amended my OP. Hopefully the extent of my ignorance is now clearer!

Comment: For (2), you just have to note that $d \longmapsto n/d$ is a bijection from the set of positive divisors of $n$ into itself. Try looking at how it works for, say, $n=4, 10, 24$ for example.

Comment: OK, feeling silly now. I'll mark as answered, and work on it in my own time!  Much appreciated.

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward I put some output, then the output reverse ordered, then that little program. To create the first several CA numbers, just begin with $1$ and multiply by the prime in the next line (the exponents will agree automatically, that is just for error checking.

Answer (score 1):

Briggs outlines an approach in his paper [Abundant Numbers and the Riemann Hypothesis](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.em/1175789744). Another method would be to multiply the primes found in the integer sequence [A073751](https://oeis.org/A073751). Additional methods can be found in the appendix of [Schwabhäuser](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.3678.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Colossally_Abundant_construct_deltas 0.01
0.5849625007211564           2           1
0.2223924213364479           2           2
0.0995356735509147           2           3
0.0473057147783566           2           4
0.0230836131130409           2           5
0.0114047632722493           2           6
0.2618595071429147           3           1
0.0728580123298782           3           2
0.0230452619595065           3           3
0.1132827525593782           5           1
0.0203734624179445           5           2
0.0686215613240664           7           1
0.0362865626271021          11           1
0.0288925673866187          13           1
0.0201744121952064          17           1
0.0174203964661791          19           1
0.0135734947947221          23           1
0.0100678863359082          29           1
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ 
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ 


jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Colossally_Abundant_construct_deltas 0.01 | sort -n -r
0.5849625007211564           2           1
0.2618595071429147           3           1
0.2223924213364479           2           2
0.1132827525593782           5           1
0.0995356735509147           2           3
0.0728580123298782           3           2
0.0686215613240664           7           1
0.0473057147783566           2           4
0.0362865626271021          11           1
0.0288925673866187          13           1
0.0230836131130409           2           5
0.0230452619595065           3           3
0.0203734624179445           5           2
0.0201744121952064          17           1
0.0174203964661791          19           1
0.0135734947947221          23           1
0.0114047632722493           2           6
0.0100678863359082          29           1
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ 
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <strstream>
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <gmpxx.h>
#include "form.h"  // after gmp.h and gmpxx.h

using namespace std;

//  g++  -o Colossally_Abundant_construct_deltas Colossally_Abundant_construct_deltas.cc  -lgmp -lgmpxx


//       ./Colossally_Abundant_construct_deltas


// save in temp.txt   then
// sort -n -r temp.txt > Colossally_Abundant_Deltas.txt





int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if ( argc != 2) cout << "Usage: ./Colossally_Abundant_construct_deltas LowerBound  " << endl;
  else {


   double bound = 0.5  ;


   bound = atof(argv[1]);


  int goon = 1;

   for (mpz_class p = 2; goon && p < 100100; p += 1)
   {
      if( mp_PrimeQ(p) )
      {    

         mpz_class q = p;
        double eps = 1.0;
        for (int k = 1; k <= 500 && eps > bound; ++k)
        {
           q *= p;
   double mu = mp_Log( q - 1 ) ;
          mu -= mp_Log( q - p ) ;
          mu /=  mp_Log( p);

  cout.precision(16);
  cout.setf(ios::fixed, ios::floatfield);  // DD page 582
        if ( mu > bound)         cout << mu <<   setw(12) << p <<   setw(12) << k << endl;
         eps = mu;
         goon = ( k > 1 ) || (mu >= bound);

        }  // for k
      } // if prime
   }//  for p
   } // else argc 
    return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ 
    jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ 
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Colossally_Abundant_construct_deltas 0.001 > temp.txt
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ sort -n -r temp.txt > Colossally_Abundant_Deltas.txt
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ cat Colossally_Abundant_Deltas.txt
0.5849625007211564           2           1
0.2618595071429147           3           1
0.2223924213364479           2           2
```

..........and so on  ..........

Compare output below with
 https://oeis.org/A004490/b004490.txt
which comes from https://oeis.org/A004490

```
  1   2  2   log ten:   0.30103
  2   3  6   log ten:   0.778151
  3   2  12   log ten:   1.07918
  4   5  60   log ten:   1.77815
  5   2  120   log ten:   2.07918
  6   3  360   log ten:   2.5563
  7   7  2520   log ten:   3.4014
  8   2  5040   log ten:   3.70243
  9  11  55440   log ten:   4.74382
 10  13  720720   log ten:   5.85777
 11   2  1441440   log ten:   6.1588
 12   3  4324320   log ten:   6.63592
 13   5  21621600   log ten:   7.33489
 14  17  367567200   log ten:   8.56534
 15  19  6983776800   log ten:   9.84409
 16  23  160626866400   log ten:   11.2058
 17   2  321253732800   log ten:   11.5068
 18  29  9316358251200   log ten:   12.9692
 19  31  288807105787200   log ten:   14.4606
 20   7  2021649740510400   log ten:   15.3057
 21   3  6064949221531200   log ten:   15.7828
 22  37  224403121196654400   log ten:   17.351
 23  41  9200527969062830400   log ten:   18.9638
 24  43  395622702669701707200   log ten:   20.5973
 25   2  791245405339403414400   log ten:   20.8983
 26  47  37188534050951960476800   log ten:   22.5704
 27  53  1970992304700453905270400   log ten:   24.2947
 28  59  116288545977326780410953600   log ten:   26.0655
 29   5  581442729886633902054768000   log ten:   26.7645
 30  61  35468006523084668025340848000   log ten:   28.5498
 31  67  2376356437046672757697836816000   log ten:   30.3759
 32  71  168721307030313765796546413936000   log ten:   32.2272
 33  73  12316655413212904903147888217328000   log ten:   34.0905
 34  11  135483209545341953934626770390608000   log ten:   35.1319
 35  79  10703173554082014360835514860858032000   log ten:   37.0295
```

=====================